# Move the marker on the map like GPS by PhoneGap

Tags: javascript, android, html, google-maps, cordova

On an application built in HTML5 + PhoneGap,

how can I make a marker on a map of Google-maps, to move to the exact location with every movement of the device **like in GPS**

Can it be done **via JS**? 
If not, through the Android It is also fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not move the marker with the JS, but I moved it with PhoneGap,

see this question:

[onlocationchanged function never called-> PhoneGap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14196074/onlocationchanged-function-never-called-phonegap/14234210#14234210)