# onlocationchanged function never called-> PhoneGap

Tags: java, javascript, android, html, cordova

I have an application written in `HTML5` and wrapped in `PhoneGap`.

I have a map on an application and I want to find a user's location by GPS.

I tried it the following way:

In JS I have a function that changes the position of the marker:

```
function GPS(lat, lon) {
    alert('Now U move');
    var CurrentPosition = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lon);
    markerMyLoc.setPosition(CurrentPosition);
}
```

In Java, I have functions that care on location and send the JS function:

```
public class MainActivity extends DroidGap {

private LocationManager locationManager;
private LocationListener locationListener;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    super.setIntegerProperty("splashscreen", R.drawable.splash);
    super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/XXX.html", 10000);

     locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);  

     locationListener = new GPSLocationListener();

      locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
        LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 
        0, 
        0, 
        locationListener);

    } 
}
```

GPSLocationListener class:

```
public class GPSLocationListener implements LocationListener 
{
  @Override
  public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    if (location != null) {
        GPScls MyGPS= new GPScls();
        MyGPS.GPS(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude());
    }
  }

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
}
```

GPScls class:

```
public class GPScls extends DroidGap {
    public void GPS(double latitude,double longitude) {
        super.loadUrl("javascript:GPS("+latitude+","+longitude+")");
    }
}
```

the alert: `alert('Now U move');` Not shown, can anyone help me solve this?

Comment: I want every movement of the device, will appear the message (ie run function), if you can also tell me how I can say to map to move in the direction the device is moving?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that, I did not go enough to return an answer from GPS

Look at the following question:

[Is the function onLocationChanged called every movement of Android device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14231632/is-the-function-onlocationchanged-called-every-movement-of-android-device)