# Is the function onLocationChanged called every movement of Android device?

Tags: java, javascript, android, html, cordova

I use the function onLocationChanged to identify the user's location, I want it to happen **every movement** of `Android` phone

exactly when the function is called?

My code looks like this:

```
locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);  
locationListener = new GPSLocationListener();
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
```

GPSLocationListener:

```
public class GPSLocationListener extends DroidGap implements LocationListener 
{
  @Override
  public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
      AlertDialog.Builder alt_bld = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        alt_bld.setMessage("onLocationChanged");
        AlertDialog alert = alt_bld.create();
        alert.show();
  }

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
}
```

The alert onLocationChanged never appears.

Comment: My question is how many meters have to move the device to function will be invoked?

Comment: I want every little movement of the device this function will called

Comment: define "little movement"

Comment: When you move the device and not when it is not moving at all

Comment: "move" is a very wide notion. I'm sitting on a chair, but i'm moving.

Comment: Any movement is not something very wide. Any movement = any little movement or the phone moving or not!, In any case already managed, thanks.

Comment: i don't know. let's start simple. If i take my phone out of my pocket, do you count that as moving it ?

Comment: Also, when you lift, lower, move from side to side, While it did not standing in place - Move!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this link:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationListener.html#onLocationChanged(android.location.Location) the method is called every time the location has changed.

From my observation there is some logic behind it and it does not change evvery time (e.g. when new location is nearby the old and has worse accuracy).

EDIT:

"every little movement" can be **ACCURACY_HIGH** at the most...I think you cant get more precise than this. Reference: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Criteria.html#ACCURACY_HIGH

EDIT 2:
 To use ACCURACY_HIGH create new Criteria object and use the setters (`setHorizontalAccuracy`, ...) and then use it like this

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(locationManager.getBestProvider(locationCriteria, true), 1L, 2F, this);
```

Comment: So, is there any way of knowing little movement of the device?

Comment: How do i use ACCURACY_HIGH?

Answer (score 1):

It depends of arguments sent to:
`requestLocationUpdates (String provider, long minTime, float minDistance, LocationListener listener)`

> **minTime**   - minimum time interval between location updates, in milliseconds
>   **minDistance**    - minimum distance between location updates,
>   in meters

Location updates are received by [LocationListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationListener.html) callbacks

[See here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#requestLocationUpdates%28long,%20float,%20android.location.Criteria,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29) for more info.

Comment: I defined these two variables as 0

Comment: This means you set to obtain notifications as frequently as possible, but the `onLocationChanged` will be triggered only when a new location will be found.

Comment: My question is when the GPS finds a new location? Every few meters?

Comment: When I am disconnecting the WiFi my location changes, I see it by a marker that I have on the map, but the function is not called ..

Comment: It tries to find a new location depending on the minTime/minDistance parameters. But GPS provider determines location using satellites. Depending on conditions, this provider may take a while to return a location fix. So you cannot garuantee that there's a fixed rate when it is fired and returns a new location.

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation of

> `requestLocationUpdates(String provider, long minTime, float
>   minDistance, LocationListener listener)`

concering the `minTime` parameter:

> "the minimum time interval for notifications, in milliseconds. This
>   field is only used as a hint to conserve power, and actual time
>   between location updates may be greater or lesser than this value."

Also

```
public abstract void onLocationChanged (Location location)

Added in API level 1
Called when the location has changed.

There are no restrictions on the use of the supplied Location object.

Parameters
location    The new location, as a Location object.
```

If this is a problem for you, you could ignore calls to the callback method if a certain amount of time hasn't passed.

Hope it will help you

Comment: How do i ignore calls to the callback method? and my minTime=0

Comment: you can get more description [HERE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#requestLocationUpdates%28long,%20float,%20android.location.Criteria,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29)

Answer (score 0):

When a location is changed .When a new location details is captured by gps receiver then the method

```
onLocationChanged(Location location)
```

is called automatically.

Comment: When did it happen? After a few meters?