# Null Pointer Exception in super.loadUrl("javascript:func;") method

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, nullpointerexception, runtime-error

I want to run a method from JS side in android side. when i use

> sendJavaScript("javascript:func()")

i don't get any error but i think method from JS side not called, and when i use

> super.loadUrl("javascript:func();")

i get runtime error. I write my some part of code, please see and answer to me 
I think my problem for my activity and my context but i dont know where is my problem.

```
public class Test extends DroidGap {
   @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    super.init();
            super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
    Log.e("run javascript func from native android", "");


    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    LocationListener locationListener = new GPSLocationListener();
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000,
            0, locationListener);
   }
 }
```

GPScls:

```
public class GPScls extends DroidGap {
public void GPS(double latitude,double longitude) {
   super.loadUrl("javascript:GPS("+latitude+","+longitude+");");
    //this.sendJavascript("javascript:GPS("+latitude+","+longitude+")");
}
}
```

GPSLocationListener:

```
public class GPSLocationListener implements LocationListener{

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (location != null) {
        GPScls MyGPS= new GPScls();
        Log.e(""+location.getLatitude(), ""+location.getLongitude());
        MyGPS.GPS(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude());

    }
}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String arg0, int arg1, Bundle arg2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

 }
```

logcat:

```
05-14 14:43:00.897: D/AndroidRuntime(1148): Shutting down VM
05-14 14:43:00.897: W/dalvikvm(1148): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40cc2930)
05-14 14:43:00.983: E/AndroidRuntime(1148): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-14 14:43:00.983: E/AndroidRuntime(1148): java.lang.NullPointerException
05-14 14:43:00.983: E/AndroidRuntime(1148):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.getResources(ContextWrapper.java:89)
05-14 14:43:00.983: E/AndroidRuntime(1148):     at android.view.ContextThemeWrapper.getResources(ContextThemeWrapper.java:78)
05-14 14:43:00.983: E/AndroidRuntime(1148):     at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3224)
05-14 14:43:00.983: E/AndroidRuntime(1148):     at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3279)
05-14 14:43:00.983: E/AndroidRuntime(1148):     at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:431)
05-14 14:43:00.983: E/AndroidRuntime(1148):     at android.widget.AbsoluteLayout.<init>(AbsoluteLayout.java:52)
05-14 14:43:00.983: E/AndroidRuntime(1148):     at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:504)
05-14 14:43:00.983: E/AndroidRuntime(1148):     at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:481)
05-14 14:43:00.983: E/AndroidRuntime(1148):     at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:461)
05-14 14:43:00.983: E/AndroidRuntime(1148):     at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:450)
05-14 14:43:00.983: E/AndroidRuntime(1148):     at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:440)
05-14 14:43:00.983: E/AndroidRuntime(1148):     at org.apache.cordova.CordovaWebView.<init>(CordovaWebView.java:126)
05-14 14:43:00.983: E/AndroidRuntime(1148):     at org.apache.cordova.CordovaActivity.init(CordovaActivity.java:313)
05-14 14:43:00.983: E/AndroidRuntime(1148):     at org.apache.cordova.CordovaActivity.loadUrl(CordovaActivity.java:376)
05-14 14:43:00.983: E/AndroidRuntime(1148):     at org.example.testphonegap.GPScls.GPS(GPScls.java:7)
05-14 14:43:00.983: E/AndroidRuntime(1148):     at org.example.testphonegap.GPSLocationListener.onLocationChanged(GPSLocationListener.java:18)
05-14 14:43:00.983: E/AndroidRuntime(1148):     at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport._handleMessage(LocationManager.java:255)
05-14 14:43:00.983: E/AndroidRuntime(1148):     at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport.access$000(LocationManager.java:184)
05-14 14:43:00.983: E/AndroidRuntime(1148):     at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport$1.handleMessage(LocationManager.java:200)
05-14 14:43:00.983: E/AndroidRuntime(1148):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-14 14:43:00.983: E/AndroidRuntime(1148):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-14 14:43:00.983: E/AndroidRuntime(1148):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
05-14 14:43:00.983: E/AndroidRuntime(1148):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-14 14:43:00.983: E/AndroidRuntime(1148):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-14 14:43:00.983: E/AndroidRuntime(1148):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
05-14 14:43:00.983: E/AndroidRuntime(1148):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
05-14 14:43:00.983: E/AndroidRuntime(1148):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-14 14:43:05.186: I/Process(1148): Sending signal. PID: 1148 SIG: 9
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`DroidGap` is an `Activity` and you cannot instantiate activity classes with `new`. Specifically, this is wrong:

```
GPScls MyGPS= new GPScls();
```

Only use `Intent` to instantiate activities. In this case it seems you should be calling `loadUrl()` on a `DroidGap` activity already instantiated for you.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. I cant understand what do you mean :( where should i use loadUrl()? i use loadUrl() method in GPScls. Please more explain for me . Thanks

Comment: You have your main activity somewhere that is declared in the manifest and instantiated by the system. Use it.

Comment: And another thing, i use this code from this link "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14196074/onlocationchanged-function-never-called-phonegap" . I searched about how can i send lat and long from android to JS. and i found this .

Comment: My main activity in manifest is Test class and i use loadUrl() in Test calss but i want in GPScls class send lat and long to JS and for this i use loadUrl() .

Comment: Questions with problems in code are rarely useful sources for exemplary code snippets...

Comment: And you can help me, how can i solve this problem? I cant understand how can send my lat and long to JS side. Please more explain with snippet code. Thanks

Comment: I have this question like user3209380. laalto please if you know say correct answer. Thanks